# Reprojecting non 4326 WMS image to spherical mercator

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system

In OpenLayers, I'm trying to display a WMS overlay (EPSG:4269) from a server I don't have control over to a spherical mercator projection.

Is there an equivalent to this:
http://blog.sumbera.com/2010/02/17/overlay-wms-on-google-in-openlayers/

for projections other than EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the option to define your projection in the WMS request query string is not available?

Comment: Yes, the only option available is 4269 :-(  http://activefiremaps.fs.fed.us/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=conus.map&%20SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&version=1.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will have a hard time doing such a reprojection directly in a web-client (i.e., a web browser).  You should check out [MapProxy](http://mapproxy.org/) which does allow one to accomplish things like this - even for WMS that you don't necessarily manage.

Comment: Thanks for the link -- that would be very helpful, but I don't have the permissions or "clearance" to add any software to our web server. I was trying to see if there is another way to do it.

Comment: Can you set up any type (.NET, Java, PHP, Python...etc) of web service in your environment?

Comment: No, anything sysadmin'esque is forbidden.